# rest api - Abort object creation in serializer create method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm wondering whether serializer create method is a good place for aborting object(model) creation. Let consider following code:

```python
class TestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('url', ...)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if everything_is_ok:
           return super().create(validated_data)
        else: #if something is wrong with data abort object creation and rise exception that will led to 400 or sth 
           ???
```

From my perspective it looks ok, because I'm using many serializers and here I have code only related to that particular one. Nevertheless I'm not sure if this is correct way (maybe create method of ModelViewSet would be better?)

If serializer create method is ok, how should I do it properly (raise exception or rather return 400 Response directly)

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you need to create more than one object use the transaction i.e `with transaction.atomic`

Comment: Hello, no I don't need to do it. I want only to return 400 when some variable e.g. will be outside allowed range, etc...

Comment: Then `raise 400` can use any of `from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError`